# Объявление функции, похожее на создание объекта

Tags: c++

```
class Test { };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test t(); // Что делает этот оператор

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это частный пример явления, известного в С++ под именем "[most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)". В ситуациях, когда в объявлении возникает неоднозначность между определением объекта и объявлением функции, эта неоднозначность в С++ разрешается в пользу объявления функции.

В вашем случае имеет место простейший пример именно такой неоднозначности. В соответствии с вышеприведенным правилом, данное объявление трактуется как объявление *функции* `t`, не имеющей параметров и возвращающей значение типа `Test`.

Для определения именно *объекта* c выполнением value-инициализации можно воспользоваться современным (С++11 и далее) синтаксисом *униформной инициализации*, который не страдает от этой неоднозначности

```
Test t{};
```

Хотя в случае именно вашего (т.е. "пустого") класса `Test` явный инициализатор не имеет никакого значения вообще и можно просто написать

```
Test t;
```

Comment: Можно еще вариант `Test t = Test();` предложить :)

Comment: @Harry, если уж и предлагать подобное, то `auto t = Test();`, хотя всё это смысла не имеет, т.к. предложенные в ответе варианты являются каноническими.

Comment: @Harry, всяких лишних вызовов в твоей схеме не будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Насколько я понимаю (*"По-моему, так"* :)) - то реально - нет, а начиная с С++17 и согласно стандарту тоже?...

Comment: @Harry: До C++17 этот вариант не гарантировал отстутствия лишних вызовов (конструктор копирования) и требовал наличия доступного конструктора копирования (даже если он не вызывался). Эти недостатки исчезли только в С++17, где появилось гарантированное copy elision и ушло требование наличия конструктора копирования. Однако уже начиная с С++11 у нас есть вариант с `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

Как я понимаю это объявление функции с прототипом Test t();  в зоне видимости main.

Comment: Зачем публиковать это ответом на свой вопрос? Это должно быть частью вопроса.

Comment: @ixSci интересно, перенесет ли это новоизбранный модератор в вопрос и лишит тем самым участника +50 реп или нет.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, стоит принять соседний ответ, поскольку в нём расписано гораздо подробнее и лучше. Я понимаю, что тот ответ был опубликован раньше того и, в принципе, является ответом, но в будущем стоит публиковать более качественные ответы.